# how do i group Nodejs MYSQL related tables as JSON and send result to the client?

Tags: javascript, node.js

i want to send back to the client Mysql related tables as JSON From NodeJS .
example like this:
i have students table and student Country table .
 where students table has field named country_id related country table.
finally what i want is to return to the client side.

all student information with student country assigned into field naming country

```
   //this is poth tables
   SELECT * FROM students s;
   SELECT * FROM country;
```

and i want  every student table and  country table to reformat as this

```
   students = [
    {
      studentId: 1,
      studentName: 'Tusbahle',
      country: {
        id: 1,
        country: 'Somalia'
      }
    },
    {
      studentId: 2,
      studentName: 'Alex',
      country: {
        id: 1,
        country: 'UK'
      }
    }
  ]
```

any help.

Comment: You can use `JSON.stringify(object)` and send it as a response from your node backend via a subscribed service to the frontend..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your SQL statement should look something like this:

```sql
SELECT s.student_id, s.student_name, s.country_id, c.country_name
FROM students s
INNER JOIN country c 
ON s.country_id = c.id;
```

(I make the assumption that the your data is represented in the database as is in the JSON you sent). if not: feel free to replace as needed (c.country_name, c.id, s.student_name etc)

next all you really need to do is something like:

i updated return keyword..

```
students = rows.map(row => {
return {
    studentId: row.student_id,
    studentName: row.student_name,
    country:{
        id: row.country_id,
        country: row.country_name
    }
}
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using routes of express, then you can send data from nodejs to that route, by this
"variable" this will contain data of table 
    res.render('page.html', {data:variable});
you can access data variable in html template like this
if this is array

```
{% for obj in data %}
   // use this
{% endfor %}
```

It will work, but if your are using template engine, if you aren't then add swig or other template engine like this before routes

```
const swig = require('swig')
app.engine('html', swig.renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'html');
```

Comment: sir this is not what i'm looking for . i edited my question as my need

Comment: ok now i got it, how are you calling client end? or you using express routes for client urls ?

Comment: express routes   router.post("/students",(req,res,next)=>{ /.... }) . and client angular